# WebScraping with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I was wondering if someone can give me an example of how to web scrape multiple pages with Node.js? I am finding examples online but I want to scrape a search result webpage. Then if there is a "next" button to move to the next page and view more results, I want to move to the next page and scrape it as well.

Has anyone done something similar to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed something like this to work using [**nightmare.js**](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare). It let's you `click('#someElement')` and `wait('#someElement')`, getting the page content between these actions using `evaluate`. **It must be in websites that let you do that**, note that you may need a `while` using the `nightmare.exists` or a `for` using the page count, for that you may need to use a query selector that can get all specified elements, like `document.querySelectorAll('.nextPageElement').length` (using the [**querySelectorAll**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-selector)) to get that count. Just try to keep using [variable lifting](https://github.com/rosshinkley/nightmare-examples/blob/master/docs/common-pitfalls/variable-lifting.md) when needed and don't fall in a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) then nightmare.js will do the job.